# How to copy or update table indexes and constraints from different database?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a production Oracle 11g database that was table dropped by a developer who is trying to integrate into an internal web app. He said he forgot he is connected to the production database and run his command `php artisan migrate:fresh` which I searched for it and it drops all tables and recreates it.

He then tried to recover all tables by using the flashback command. Everything was recovered but indexes, keys and constraints are renamed.

Is it possible to copy/update the table structure(index, keys, constraints) of our backup database to the affected database?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no direct way of getting the desired names of the constraints and Indexes, But yes you can achieve it with a little bit of manual work as following.

First of all, You can change the constraint name using following command:

```
alter table <table_name> rename constraint <constarint_name> to <new_constarint_name>;
```

The same way, you can change the Index name using the following command:

```
ALTER INDEX <index_name> RENAME TO <new_index_name>;
```

In your case, you need some way to link bad(constraints/Indexes) names with correct names. and then rename the constraints/Indexes with the correct name. To achieve it, you can try the following steps. (I am giving example for Constraints, you can achieve the same for indexes)

- **Step 1**

Get the constraint names and their data from **production DB** using the following query and **make one table in Backup DB** using that data. (You can use `SQL Loader` or `External table` for it.) Give the name of this table as `PROD_DB_CONS`

```
SELECT
    C.TABLE_NAME,
    C.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
    LISTAGG(CC.COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                COLUMN_NAME
        ) CONS_COLUMNS
FROM
    USER_CONSTRAINTS C
    JOIN USER_CONS_COLUMNS CC ON ( C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME )
GROUP BY
    C.TABLE_NAME,
    C.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE;
```

- **Step 2**

Create the same type of table in **backup DB** using following query:

```
CREATE TABLE BACKUP_DB_CONS AS
SELECT
    C.TABLE_NAME,
    C.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
    LISTAGG(CC.COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                COLUMN_NAME
        ) CONS_COLUMNS
FROM
    USER_CONSTRAINTS C
    JOIN USER_CONS_COLUMNS CC ON ( C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME )
GROUP BY
    C.TABLE_NAME,
    C.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE;
```

- **Step 3**

Execute the following query in **Backup DB** which will generate a series of commands to change the name of all the constraints of production DB

```
SELECT
    'ALTER TABLE '
    || B.TABLE_NAME
    || ' RENAME CONSTRAINT '
    || P.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    || ' TO '
    || B.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    || ';'
FROM
    BACKUP_DB_CONS B
    JOIN PROD_DB_CONS P ON ( B.TABLE_NAME = P.TABLE_NAME
                             AND B.CONS_COLUMNS = P.CONS_COLUMNS );
```

- **Step 4**

Copy all the commands and execute all of them in **production DB**.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for this.

For the **Step 3**, the query outputs the records which already have the same constraint_name, the correct names.

I want to query the records wich contraint_names are changed because of the drop. For my table, they start with BIN$.

I made some changes but not really sure if it's correct.

```

Comment: Here's my updated code. Can you please check


`
SELECT
    'ALTER TABLE '
    || B.TABLE_NAME
    || ' RENAME CONSTRAINT '
    || P.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    || ' TO '
    || B.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    || ';'
FROM
    BACKUP_DB_CONS B
    JOIN PROD_DB_CONS P ON ( B.TABLE_NAME = P.TABLE_NAME
                             AND B.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = P.CONSTRAINT_TYPE AND B.CONS_COLUMNS = P.CONS_COLUMNS );
`

Comment: Try this: `SELECT
    'ALTER TABLE '
    || B.TABLE_NAME
    || ' RENAME CONSTRAINT '
    || P.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    || ' TO '
    || B.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    || ';'
FROM
    BACKUP_DB_CONS B
    JOIN PROD_DB_CONS P ON ( B.TABLE_NAME = P.TABLE_NAME
                             AND B.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = P.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
                             AND B.CONS_COLUMNS = P.CONS_COLUMNS 
                             AND B.CONSTRAINT_NAME <> P.CONSTRAINT_NAME);`

Comment: Thank you so much. For Indexes, what table should I use?

Comment: `USER_INDEXES` and `USER_IND_COLUMNS`