# How to query all foreign keys from a backup db and add it to a production db?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I query all foreign keys of a backup database and use it to add on a production database?

We accidentally dropped all tables of our production database. We were able to recover all using the `flashback` method. With some scripts and manual procedures, we were able to rename all the constraints, indexes, and triggers back to their original name by referencing it to our backup database.

I think the last thing to recover now is the foreign keys. How could we query all the foreign keys with all their respective links/columns/tables and make a script to add it back to our production database?

Comment: Why didn't you just restore the database? Then everything would have been identical. Or did the backup not contain the most recent data?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't contain all the recent data. Indeed, it would have been easy restore. So basically, all we need is to restore the original structure.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you export/import that table from backup database ?

If you have table in your backup database then use expdp to backup table and impdp to generate sql script with "sqlfile" option .

if you want it generate only foreign key script then use include option INCLUDE=REF_CONSTRAINT.

Comment: Yes, we could do that but we're talking about 400+ of tables. All these tables were accidentally dropped by a PHP developer with the command ```php artisan migrate:fresh``` on the app that he's developing.

We're looking for a more systematic way just like how we renamed the indexes and constraints from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215993/how-to-copy-or-update-table-indexes-and-constraints-from-different-database/58216894?noredirect=1#comment102862237_58216894)